# Update the text get from listView.onItemClick to a button

Tags: android, listview, button

I did managed to get the text from the listView.onItemClick, while when I set the text to a button I'm getting an error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Update the full code below:
SubjectDialogActivity.java

```
package x.reminder;

import ...;

public class SubjectDialogActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listViewSubject;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListSubject;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterSubject;
    String subjectText;
    Button btnSub;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_subject);

        //Sizing...

        //Create list...

        //Errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
        //Set On Click
        listViewSubject.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                btnSub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubject);
                String selectedText = listViewSubject.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); 
                btnSub.setText(selectedText);

            }
        });
    }


    public void addSubjectClick(View v){
        ...
        intent.setClass(SubjectDialogActivity.this, AddSubjectActivity.class);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult...
    }
}
```

xml - activity_add.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout ...">

<LinearLayout
  ...>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnSubject"
...
android:text="Subject"
android:onClick="showDialogSubjectList"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `R.id.btnSubject` check this present or not in xml

Comment: .... and It must present into your `ROW_layout.xml`

Comment: There is. <Button android:id="@+id/btnSubject" .../> While it's not the one in the setContentView(R.layout.***). Will that be the problem? If so how could we define it?

Comment: i think button is not inside the listView item..??

Comment: The button's in another activity, not within the listView

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe when you wire your attributes to your xml, it should be done at the beginning of onCreate method.

As for the error, you need to locate the null object which in this case is your button. Try moving your findviewbyid part in onCreate

Comment: Unfortunately moving that to the start of onCreate didn't works :/

Comment: Update the question with full code of the class and the xml file please

Comment: I have updated the code,, while as the site won't allow to submit too much code I have replace some of them with '...'.

Comment: Lets try to figure out the actual problem, can you place the findviewbyid part in onCreate method and also write btn.settext("testing") and see if the error continues

Comment: Yeah.. the error's still there, I actually wonder if it's because the xml file where the button is located is not set in the setContentView() on this java class?

Comment: Haha the first thing we needed to check...
setContentView(R.layout.activity_add) 
This will speak to the xml where your button is located. A single activity class can only be responsible for a single xml as far as I know.

Comment: Oh.. that's sad :( I found someone using the LayoutInflater() to solve this issue,, but not working for me atm,, I'll do some further debug and update the result. Thank you very much for helping :D

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? Maybe I can suggest an alternative route.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve: (1st activity)**Button** onclick > (within 1st activity) pop-up-dialog with a listview & float button > (2nd activity)floatbutton onclick will create a listitem with inserted text (back to dialog) > dialog's listItem onclick will back to the initial button page & change the text of the **button** to the text of the clicked listItem. The functionality's simple but there's several activities involved :/

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectedText = arrayListSubject.get(position);
```